How can i turn off this tag's highlight?
(https://i.sstatic.net/Lzyn3.png)
So some of my tags are highlightning, idk why??? help im begging on my knees, cant see code of this
I try this already in settings.js:
 "editor.matchBrackets": "never", "editor.occurrencesHighlight": "off", "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
didnt work at all, cant find anything else, eheeeeelppp =(

Seems like there is an issue with the theme you're using. Try using some another theme extensions. I'm using this theme, it looks great.


I've got installed "React Import Highlighter" expansion........ thats rly braindead movement
